# Get primary keys after update in SQLAlchemy Core?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've been using `.inserted_primary_key` in SQLAlchemy to get primary keys after inserts, for example:

```
my_id = sql_conn.execute(my_table.insert(my_data_dict)).inserted_primary_key
```

Is there a way to get the same thing after an update? Like:

```
my_id = sql_conn.execute(
    my_table.update().where(some_cond).values(my_data_dict)).updated_primary_key
```

I'm on MySQL and I could do this with actual SQL like:

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE some_table SET column_name = 'value', id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
WHERE some_other_column = 'blah' LIMIT 1; 
SELECT @update_id;
```

Any way to mimic that, or something like it?

Comment: Your update could apply in more than one registry. In this case, would you like to retrieve the list of pk?

Comment: You can always just do `session.execute("SET ...; UPDATE ...; SELECT ...;")`.

Comment: @univerio thanks! Your approach works, but I was hoping for a built in. Doing the literal SQL approach would make my code longer, uglier, and less portable. I'll do it if I have to, but was hoping for an alternative.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi yes, that was the idea. Basically same behavior as `.inserted_primary_key` (i.e. on batch inserts) but for an update statement.